# Proper set up for using slideToggle

Tags: jquery, toggle, expressionengine, each

Guys i'm trying to get a list of posts and it's content not to display on page load but within each div there is a expand button that would expand just that particular post. Here is the code that I have so far:

```
<div class="postEntry">

    <div class="collapsibleContent">
         <div class="postContent"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="actionDiv">
        <span id="actionWording">Read More</span>
        <a href="#" id="actionLink" class="open"></a>
    </div>

</div>

<div class="postEntry">

    <div class="collapsibleContent">
         <div class="postContent"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="actionDiv">
        <span id="actionWording">Read More</span>
        <a href="#" id="actionLink" class="open"></a>
    </div>

</div>
```

I would like to make actionDiv clickable so that the content will display but ALSO have the wording within actionWording change to COLLAPSE if content is expanded. actionLink is an anchor tag that has a background image set by css and the class open close.

This is what I have for JS:

```
jQuery(function()
{

  $('.collapsibleContent').each(function() {
    $(this).css('display', 'none');
  });

  $('.actionButton').click(function() {
    $(this).next('.collapsibleContent').slideToggle('fast')
    return false;
  });

});
```

Comment: You should know that `ID` must be unique inside a document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/ocajud/8/edit)*

look for `.prev()` and use `.hide()` method, and you don't need return false unless you use *anchors*, but in that case I'd suggest to use `event.preventDefault()`

```
$(function(){

  $('.collapsibleContent').hide();
  
  $('.actionButton').click(function( ev ) {
      ev.preventDefault();

      var visible = $(this).prev('.collapsibleContent').is(':visible'),
         slideTog = visible?'slideUp':'slideDown',
              txt = visible?'EXPAND':'COLLAPSE';
       
      $('.collapsibleContent').slideUp().next('.actionButton').text('EXPAND');
      
      $(this).text( txt ).prev('.collapsibleContent')[slideTog]();

  });
   
});
```

Comment: This does work, but how can I also change EXPAND which is within the actionButton div to COLLAPSE. Thank you

Comment: @TikaL13 Thanks you. how you mean 'change' ? change what?

Comment: Would like to also have the other close if one is EXPANDED. Thanks again!

Comment: The wording. So when you click on the actionButton I would like the text within that div to say COLLAPSE and vis versa when closed to reset to EXPAND.

Comment: see my answer for EXPAND/COLLAPSE

Comment: @TikaL13 done! happy coding and if you have questions feel free to ask.

Comment: @roXon thanks! I made a slight change and wanted to run it by you and see how this effects your code.

Comment: Just tell me, do you plan to have more modifications? What do you exactly don't understand in my answer? Do you find it hard to implement it with your changes?

Comment: @roXon Sorry for the confusion but this is that I have: http://bitly.com/UlwTXI here is my JS: http://pastebin.com/btuKHtw1

Comment: I edited my answer a couple of times. Your demo is quite different from what I suggested latest. and BTW on click use `event.preventDefault()` to prevent the page jump-to-top on click

Answer (score 2):

Should be like this(by using `parent()`):

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $('.collapsibleContent').css('display', 'none');

  $('.actionButton').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().find('.collapsibleContent').slideToggle('fast');
    if ( $(this).html() == 'COLLAPSE' )
      $(this).html('EXPAND');
    else
      $(this).html('COLLAPSE');
  });

});
```